# Custom template in X-editable is ignored

Tags: javascript, html, x-editable

According to the [documentation of X-editable](https://vitalets.github.io/bootstrap-editable/), there is a `template` attribute. It allows to specify the used input element like textarea. But it seems to be ignored in my app. So I tried a simple example like in the docs:

```
<a href="#" id="test"></a>
```

Called by this JS

```
$('#test').editable({
    template: '<textarea rows="1"></textarea>'
});
```

I got the x-editable, but the basic one, which has a input element inside:

```
<input type="text" class="form-control input-sm" style="padding-right: 24px;">
```

Couldn't find any information whats I'm doing wrong here. The latest Version v1.5.1  is used.

Answer (score 0):

Found my mistake: A few years ago, [Bootstrap editable](https://github.com/vitalets/bootstrap-editable) was renamed to [x-editable](https://github.com/vitalets/x-editable). Some attributes were renamed. For example, `template` to `tpl`. That's the reason, why the attribute is ignored. I didn't noticed this yet, since I'm new to the component.

Secondly, there is a custom `rows` attribute. So a template isn't neccessary to customize the rows. You could simply use

```
$('#test').editable({
    type: 'textarea',
    rows: 10
});
```

But it's also possible to define a custom template. For example, when you want to apply CSS (classes) or something else:

```
$('#test').editable({
    type: 'textarea',
    tpl: '<textarea id="my-id"></textarea>'
});
```

The actual information about possible options can be found in the [new documentation of x-editable](http://vitalets.github.io/x-editable/docs.html).